# How to fix log in screen loop error in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

After I've updated Kali Linux, I can't log in anymore. When I enter the password login screen just reappears over and over again.

What have I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

fixing updates:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

reinstalling gnome (and several other desktops)

```
sudo apt update sudo apt install kali-desktop-gnome
```

And finishing interrupted updates:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

(also when I type in this command nothing happens)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that here.

Get to a terminal screen with Ctrl-Alt-F1 .  Log in.

Then, sudo apt autoremove .

Restart and you should be able to login normally.

Then run normal update again.

This has worked for me.